# Joining intersected polylines using rules based rendering

Tags: qgis, line, rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting rendering order of line layers in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/setting-rendering-order-of-line-layers-in-qgis)

I have trouble getting two intersecting polylines to look like they were joined at rendering. I am using rules based rendering and these two lines are rendered with same rules, so they look identical. One line ends where the other begings, but the line does not render to look smooth - rather it renders the end of other line.

Example:

[image: http://s8.postimage.org/j4nvf2ubp/rendering_problem.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it by myself.

As the line symbol I use is made of two overlapping lines, I simply had to open the "Rendering order" and change the darker, wider line to higher rendering layer.

So: Wide/dark line symbol's rendering order to layer 0 and narrow/brighter line symbol's rendering order to layer 1 -> The lines look merged after rendering.