# In QGIS, how to control the rendering order of objects in a single layer with rule-based symbology?

Tags: qgis, rendering

In QGIS 2.18, I have a symbology of points in a layer based on rules.
I want to control the rendering order of the layer in QGIS, with on top the type with the lower counts.
[image]
Intuitively I would expect to observe a rendering order modification by drag-droping the types, but this does not occur. A [related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/setting-rendering-order-of-line-layers-in-qgis) is of no help.

As you can see on the image I have tried using the "control features rendering order" but without success.

How could I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Symbol Levels, and there choose the order of rendering. Categories with lower number will be rendered first, and thus will show below categories with higher number.

[image: Where to find Symbol levels]

[image: Symbol levels in action]

In the above example, *drive oui* is below *drive NULL*, and both are below *drive non*.